# Navigating through the materials of a imported 3d model mesh that has 2 or more materials - A-Frame / Three JS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I am working on A-Frame with a 3D model imported from Blender. Multiple meshes of this model have 2 or more materials assigned to them.

I can change the material properties of meshes that have only 1 material

However, when it comes to changing the material properties of meshes that have more than one material, I run into the following problem:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'opacity')"

The code I am using is the following:

```
    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('modify-materials', {
        init: function () {
          // Wait for model to load.
          this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
            // Grab the mesh / scene.
            const obj = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
            // Go over the submeshes and modify materials we want.
            obj.traverse(node => {
              if (node.name.indexOf('muros') !== -1) {
                node.material.opacity = 1;
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
```

I was assuming the solution was going to be as simple as treating the materials as an array, but it didn't work:

```
node.material[0].opacity = 1;
node.materials[0].opacity = 1;
```

I have also searched how to iterate between the id's of materials but I have not been successful.

Could someone help me understand how I can access the 2,3,4,n materials?

Comment: is muros the name of the material or the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

Each `mesh` node should have only one `material`. So you should probably search by the material name, and modify the ones that match:

```
obj.traverse(node => {
  if (node.material.name === "material_one") {
    node.material.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    node.material.opacity = 0.5;
  }
});
```

---

I remember doing something similar - check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/PlanetVoodoo/material-modifier/). Knowing the material name, you can modify its properties ([like here](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/PlanetVoodoo/material-modifier/index.html#L80-L83)):

```
<a-entity gltf-model="./model.gltf" 
          material-modifier__MaterialName="emissive: 0xffff00"
          material-modifier__AnotherMaterialName="color: 0xff00ff"
></a-entity>
```